# Persistent error with Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException

Tags: json, azure, powershell, json.net

I have been attempting to run commands from the AzureAD powershell module, but I am consistently getting Json errors.

The issue is so persistent no matter what commands I run, I am wondering if the Newtonsoft.Json package is misconfigured and needs to be reinstalled.

```
Example:

New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -Id "any id" -ResourceId "any id" -ObjectId "any id" -PrincipalID "any id"

Output:

Error reading JToken from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0 
At line:1 char:1
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -Id ....
     CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment], JsonReaderException
     FullyQualifiedErrorId: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException.Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Powershell.NewServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment.
```

Comment: Newtonsoft throws the `Error reading JToken from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.` when trying to parse an empty string (which is not well-formed JSON). See https://dotnetfiddle.net/eEuu1S.  So it's unlikely the problem is due to the Newtonsoft.Json package being misconfigured, more likely you are trying to query for something that does not exist, an empty string is returned, which causes the exception to be thrown.

Comment: [“Error reading JToken from JsonReader” when programmatically managing Azure Policy with PowerShell](https://jasonmasten.com/2021/01/25/error-reading-jtoken-from-jsonreader-when-programmatically-managing-azure-policy-with-powershell/) by Jason Masten looks similar.  The recommendation there: *Use an if/else statement to ensure the “parameter” parameter is only used when it has a value:*

Comment: @dbc When I try to search for something that does not exist (on other systems where this command works)  I get an error saying so.  In this case it is as if the non-empty parameters are being serialized to an empty string.

Comment: Could you please confirm whether you are getting the error while running only the New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment command only?

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got successfully created a new app role service principal assignments:**

**Commands:**

```
Connect-AzureAD

New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId -PrincipalId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId -ResourceId $resourceApp.ObjectId -Id $permission.Id
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

Make sure you are using latest version of Newtonsoft.json.
if you are using lower version, try to uninstall and reinstall the latest version by below command:

```
Install-Module -Name newtonsoft.json -RequiredVersion 1.0.1.2
```

If the error is still persisting uninstall AzureAD module reinstall the **`AzureAD-Module`** confirm all the traffic can be passed the network policy (Firewall) .

Verify if you are using the latest version of Azure AD PowerShell module? Also, validate if your local machine's firewall is restricting the command? Or if you're connected to any VPN or organizational laptop.

If AzureAD module is already installed, Install new version(**2.0.2.140**).

**Command:**

```
Install-Module -Name AzureAD --Allowclobber
```

**Reference:**
[Getting error when running script · Issue #2 · adrecon/AzureADRecon (github.com)](https://github.com/adrecon/AzureADRecon/issues/2)